# Disabling warning that scratch layer isn't saved in QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, editing

I'm upgrading a QGIS plugin that I've written for farmers ([GeoDataFarm](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geodatafarm/)) and I wonder if it is possible to disable the warning of temporary scratch layers on the close project that was added in QGIS 3.2?

I use the scratch layer for the user to draw the field on the map, and then I use the `polygon` in WKT format to store the data on a Postgres database.
A more elegant solution might be to remove my memory layer and add it again. Hmm, any thoughts?

Here is some of my code (only some tiny bits to make sense of my question).

[image: Close project warning]

```py
def add_field(self):
    self.field = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", name, "memory")
    self.field.startEditing()
    self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.field)

def save_field(self):
    self.iface.actionSaveActiveLayerEdits().trigger()
    self.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
    feature = self.field.getFeature(1)
    polygon = feature.geometry().asWkt()
    self.db.execute_sql('insert into fields (geom) values (st_geomfromtext('{wkt}', 4326)'.format(wkt=polygon))
```

Comment: If it turns out there's no way to disable this warning, consider making a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use this code for desired results:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSettings

settings = QgsSettings()
settings.setValue('app/askToSaveMemoryLayers', False)
```

Tested: QGIS 3.24 - 6/15/23